# I want to color the particular column containing Pass & Fail Value to different color using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, jenkins-email-ext

Below is the Code, and the requirement works perfectly with JavaScript but I cannot use JS as I want to run this code in Jenkins Email Extension which doesn't support JS.

```html
<style>
  TABLE {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  TH {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  
  TD {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
  }
  
  .greenclass {
    color: green;
  }
  
  .redclass {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function createtable() {
    const cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      if (cells[i].innerHTML == "PASS") {
        cells[i].className += 'greenclass';
      }
      if (cells[i].innerHTML == "FAIL") {
        cells[i].className += 'redclass';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
      <col/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th>Transaction Name</th>
      <th>SLA</th>
      <th>Minimum</th>
      <th>Average</th>
      <th>Maximum</th>
      <th>90%</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Login</td>
      <td>10 </td>
      <td>6.02</td>
      <td>7.2</td>
      <td>9.88</td>
      <td>9.88</td>
      <td>PASS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HomePage</td>
      <td>5 </td>
      <td>1.39</td>
      <td>1.64</td>
      <td>2.31</td>
      <td>2.31</td>
      <td>PASS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Logout</td>
      <td>5 </td>
      <td>5.48</td>
      <td>5.55</td>
      <td>5.74</td>
      <td>5.74</td>
      <td>FAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <script>
      createtable();
    </script>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any cells with "pass" in them.

Comment: What script creates this email? Or is it done by hand?

Comment: This HTML content is being created by Powershell [without the JS part, I added that manually], basically I am getting a result of my Performance test in csv file and I convert that into HTML using Powershell, and then I use Jenkins - Editable Email Content Plugin to send this html content over mail.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add title to each td and then use the css selector [title~=FAIL] or [title~=PASS]

You can read abount it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp

Comment: I cannot add titles to the TD tags, the HTML file gets created automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no css selector based on content. so the only way is to use JS or change the HTML